# Need to pick Eid with following conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need to pick the Eid whose latest status is "Active" and Active status effective date must be
 "05-04-2013"
and the same Eid should satisfy the immediate previous status value as "Inactive" and InActive status effective date must be "06-30-2007"

Consider the below table:Emp

```
+-----+---------+----------+------------+
| EID |  ENAME  |  STATUS  | STATUSDATE |
+-----+---------+----------+------------+
| 101 | ABC.INC | INACTIVE | 06-30-2007 |
| 101 | ABC.INC | ACTIVE   | 05-04-2013 |
| 102 | DOC.LLC | ACTIVE   | 04-04-1997 |
| 102 | DOC.LLC | ACTIVE   | 04-04-1999 |
| 102 | DOC.LLC | INACTIVE | 04-04-2001 |
| 103 | XYZ.LLP | INACTIVE | 06-30-2007 |
| 103 | XYZ.LLP | ACTIVE   | 05-04-2009 |
| 103 | XYZ.LLP | ACTIVE   | 05-04-2013 |
+-----+---------+----------+------------+
```

Here in this table EID "101" has the latest status as "Active"  with statusdate as 05-04-2013 and it has the Immediate previous status as "InActive" with
status date as "06-30-2007".  So need to have only "101" as the output.

Output:

```
Eid
101
```

Comment: What error are you getting?   This is very simple SQL.

Comment: i am new to sql pls help

Comment: we need to use row_number() i guess

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The immediate previous status isn't inactive, it's active... for 20090504. I also hope your date column doesn't have = sign in them

Comment: Both 101 and 103 have the same StatusDate, you only want one record and one field?

Answer (score 0):

We will be using the [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function to get the previous status and statusdate ordered by statusdate and partitioned by EID. Because this is a windowed function, and windowed functions cannot be in the where clause, we make this a sub-query then apply the filters.

```
SELECT
    [EID]
FROM (
    SELECT
        [EID]
        ,[STATUS]
        ,LAG([STATUS]) OVER (PARTITION BY [EID] ORDER BY [STATUSDATE]) AS [previous_status]
        ,LAG([STATUSDATE]) OVER (PARTITION BY [EID] ORDER BY [STATUSDATE]) AS [previous_status_date]
        ,[STATUSDATE]
    FROM @tbl
    ) AS tbl2
WHERE
    [STATUS] = 'ACTIVE'
    AND [STATUSDATE] = '05-04-2013'
    AND [previous_status] = 'INACTIVE'
    AND [previous_status_date] = '06-30-2007'
```

Here is the full SQL used to test:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    [EID] INT
    ,[ENAME] VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[STATUS] VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[STATUSDATE] DATE
)

INSERT @tbl
VALUES
    (101,'ABC.INC','INACTIVE','6/30/2007')
    ,(101,'ABC.INC','ACTIVE','5/4/2013')
    ,(102,'DOC.LLC','ACTIVE','4/4/1997')
    ,(102,'DOC.LLC','ACTIVE','4/4/1999')
    ,(102,'DOC.LLC','INACTIVE','4/4/2001')
    ,(103,'XYZ.LLP','INACTIVE','6/30/2007')
    ,(103,'XYZ.LLP','ACTIVE','5/4/2009')
    ,(103,'XYZ.LLP','ACTIVE','5/4/2013')


SELECT
    [EID]
FROM (
    SELECT
        [EID]
        ,[STATUS]
        ,LAG([STATUS]) OVER (PARTITION BY [EID] ORDER BY [STATUSDATE]) AS [previous_status]
        ,LAG([STATUSDATE]) OVER (PARTITION BY [EID] ORDER BY [STATUSDATE]) AS [previous_status_date]
        ,[STATUSDATE]
    FROM @tbl
    ) AS tbl2
WHERE
    [STATUS] = 'ACTIVE'
    AND [STATUSDATE] = '05-04-2013'
    AND [previous_status] = 'INACTIVE'
    AND [previous_status_date] = '06-30-2007'
```